# Counter torque in alternator supplying reactive power

Tags: torque, alternator

When an alternator(assume zero armature resistance and iron loss) is supplying purely lagging/leading current, which means there is no work done by the current supplied, does that mean the counter electromagnetic torque offered by the alternator is theoretically zero?

Comment: If lagging or leading then torque cannot be zero, has to be work somewhere...

Comment: Ok, but where? There is no work done by the inductor or capacitor load, only work done is heat dissipated in the transmission line, which is close to zero in an experimental setup. Which means the generator effective supplies no energy?

Comment: assuming no frictional losses then yes torque changes direction as the generator/motor current. An alternator is just a AC generator with 3phase rectifier and field current controlled current out, so not reversible

Answer (score 2):

So you have a three phase (or single phase AC generator) running a reactive load

The reactive part of the load will make no torque on the shaft of the generator
it will appear mechanically as increased rotational innertia

You will likely still have some torque caused by resistive losses in the wiring ans the generator's stator windings, and if the alternator output is tapped to provide field current that will present itself as a mechanical load too, also magnetic losses, eddy currents etc...

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. While thinking more about this condition, I discovered something else too, which I don't know if its a stupid observation or not. 
During consider the first half cycle of an alternator supplying a reactive load, say purely capacitive. From the wave form we see that during the first quarter of the cycle, the current and voltage are in the same direction, meaning power flows from source to load, this creates a negative torque, counter torque on the alternator shaft.
Please read the next comment...

Comment: During the second quarter, voltage is positive, but decreasing, the conductors in the alternator are still under the same pole, but the current is negative. here the power is flowing from load to source, also since the current in the armature conductor is in the opposite direction from which it was in the first quarter cycle, the counter torque appears to be negative, i.e, in the same direction of the prime mover torque! So does that mean there is motoring action?

Comment: Does this mean alternator supplying reactive load tends to slow down and accelerate during every half cycle, but the net effect over a cycle is zero thus instantaneous supply frequency is not constant but average supply frequency is?( In the case of a single alternator supplying reactive load, with out sophisticated speed control system, but driven by a constant supply of steam)

Comment: trying to differentioate that effect from the cogging seen as the magnetic path change could be difficult.